# creating a timer that updates a label in java

Tags: java, timer, interface, frame

A question on my study guide for my test includes creating a timer which increases the value of a numeric label by 1 every 500 milliseconds. this timer should be displayed in a frame. 
Here is the code I have written for the class that makes the timer and updates the value in the frame;

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class TimerFrame extends JFrame {

private JLabel numericLabel;
private int number;



class AddListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        number = number ++;
        numericLabel.setText(number + "\n");
    }

}

public TimerFrame() {
    number = 0;
    setSize(300,400);
    ActionListener listener = new AddListener();
    Timer t = new Timer(500, listener);
    numericLabel=new JLabel();
    this.add(numericLabel);
    t.start();
}



}
```

here is my main class that will make the frame visible:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class TimerFrameTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JFrame frame = new TimerFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

when I run the main class, a frame pops up but there are no numbers on it (the label isn't showing up). SO basically it is just an empty frame. does anyone know how to fix this and make the timer change the label every 500 milliseconds?

update; the result should be made visible because I added it to the panel. but now, I am getting an error "exception in thread main"

the error that I received is below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1040)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:958)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:540)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:363)
    at TimerFrame.<init>(TimerFrame.java:27)
    at TimerFrameTest.main(TimerFrameTest.java:9)
```

update: with the updated code above, the new problem is that the timer shows up and just says "0" and does not increase in value whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't adding the label to the frame.  In your constructor do

```
this.add(numericLabel);
```

Edit: I guess you will need to create the label before you add it. :)

```
numericLabel = new JLabel();
this.add(numericLabel);
```

Comment: That makes sense, I should've seen that. Now, when I add that line of code I am getting an "exception in thread main" error

Comment: im not really sure exactly what that means, I'm new to this website. but I think I edited the question to update what the problem is

Comment: you should add the changes you made to the constructor, the stack trace is the full error that you received, should tell you what classes failed and on what lines.

Comment: The stacktrace is the error that you see in the console.  It shows all of the calls that led to the error so we can tell what line of code is causing the exception.

Comment: disregard my answer that I deleted, I was reading too fast and missed the declaration of numericLabel.

Comment: it is still saying "The method add(JLabel) is undefined for the type TimerFrame.AddListener" when I create and add the label in the constructor

Comment: The add method should be getting called from the TimerFrame constructor not the AddListener constructor.  Can you post updated code?

Comment: okay, now what is happening is the frame pops up with just "0" and the value never changes. I appreciate the help as we never practiced this concept in class and my textbook does not go into much depth about using a timer, and it will be on my exam.

Comment: try adding numericLabel.repaint() after you set the text.  You can also add a System.out.println() in your ActionListener to make sure the method is being called.

Comment: I added numericLabel.repaint() and nothing changed...then I made it "number+1" instead of "number++" and now the program works. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It looks like you had a space inbetween number and ++ which is probably why it didn't work.  You also don't need the assignment to number.  The whole line could have been number++.  Good luck on your exam.